# How to create isotope filter in drupal 7?

Tags: jquery, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-views, jquery-isotope

I have a page type, say for example we name it BULDINGTYPE. I have several BULDINGTYPE pages namely: "HotelA, HotelB, HotelC, RestaurantX, RestaurantY, FactoryM, FactoryN, ShoppingComplexG, ShoppingComplexH, ShoppingComplexI". Now I want to create a portfolio style jquery isotope filter using these three filters at the top namely "HOTEL, RESTAURANT, FACTORY, SHOPPINGCOMPLEX. When I click on HOTEL button, all pages with type Hotel will be displayed. Same for the other 3 filters. Can someone provide me a sample code or even a fiddle of doing this please? I have tried the Views_isotope module ( https://www.drupal.org/project/views_isotope ) but it doesn't seem to be working. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You need to create taxonomies for  "HOTEL, RESTAURANT, FACTORY, SHOPPINGCOMPLEX and assign this taxonomies to respective pages. **Then follow this [youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6h2NqfbWv9Q) .**

Please note that isotop filter will work only if you are using taxonomies as filter.

Comment: Can you provide me with a fiddle please? I am having problem filtering the contents

Comment: I didnt got you for fiddle. Can you elaborate it.  This is also another great [video for isotop filters](http://codekarate.com/daily-dose-of-drupal/using-jquery-isotope-display-content-views-it%E2%80%99s-fancy)

Comment: By fiddle I mean if you can provide me a working example and where I can view the code behind.